# Program crashes, Tree too large

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I'm trying to answer this problem as an exercise:

here are set of coins of {50,25,10,5,1} cents in a box.Write a program to find the number of ways a 1 dollar can be created by grouping the coins.

My solution involves making a tree with each edge having one of the values above. Each node would then hold a sum of the coins. I could then populate this tree and look for leaves that add up to 100. So here is my code

```
class TrieNode
{
public:
    TrieNode(TrieNode* Parent=NULL,int sum=0,TrieNode* FirstChild=NULL,int children=0, bool key =false )
        :pParent(Parent),pChild(FirstChild),isKey(key),Sum(sum),NoChildren(children)
    {
        if(Sum==100)
            isKey=true;
    }
    void SetChildren(int children)
    {
        pChild = new TrieNode[children]();
        NoChildren=children;
    }
    ~TrieNode(void);

    //pointers
    TrieNode* pParent;
    TrieNode* pChild;

    int NoChildren;

    bool isKey;
    int Sum;
};

void Populate(TrieNode* Root, int coins[],int size)
{
    //Set children
    Root->SetChildren(size);

    //add children
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        TrieNode* child  = &Root->pChild[0];
        int c = Root->Sum+coins[i];
        if(c<=100)
        {
            child = new TrieNode(Root,c);

            if(!child->isKey) //recursively populate if not a key
                Populate(child,coins,size);
        }
        else 
            child = NULL;
    }
}

int getNumKeys(TrieNode* Root)
{
    int keys=0;

    if(Root == NULL)
        return 0;

    //increment keys if this is a key
    if(Root->isKey)
        keys++;

    for(int i=0; i<Root->NoChildren;i++)
    {
        keys+= getNumKeys(&Root->pChild[i]);
    }

    return keys;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TrieNode* RootNode = new TrieNode(NULL,0);
    int coins[] = {50,25,10,5,1};
    int size = 5;

    Populate(RootNode,coins,size);
    int combos =  getNumKeys(RootNode);

    printf("%i",combos);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the tree is so huge that after a few seconds the program crashes. I'm running this on a windows 7, quad core, with 8gb ram. A rough calculation tells me I should have enough memory.

Are my calculations incorrect?
Does the OS limit how much memory I have access to?
Can I fix it while still using this solution?

All feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit1:**
I have verified that the above approach is wrong. By trying to build a tree with a set of  only 1 coin.
 coins[] = {1};

I found that the algorithm still failed. 
After reading the post from Lenik and from João Menighin
I came up with this solution that ties both Ideas together to make a recursive solution
which takes any sized array

```
//N is the total the coins have to amount to
int getComobs(int coins[], int size,int N)
{
    //write base cases
    //if array empty | coin value is zero or N is zero
    if(size==0 || coins[0]==0 ||N==0)
        return 0;


    int thisCoin = coins[0];
    int atMost = N / thisCoin ;

    //if only 1 coin denomination
    if(size==1)
    {
        //if all coins fit in N
        if(N%thisCoin==0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }


    int combos =0;
    //write recursion
    for(int denomination =0; denomination<atMost;denomination++)
    {
        coins++;//reduce array ptr

        combos+= getComobs(coins, size-1,N-denomination*thisCoin);

        coins--;//increment array ptr
    }

    return combos;
}
```

Thanks for all the feedback

Comment: As feedback: avoid more than 3 parameters in a constructor, use setters instead. Just that mere fact made your code much harder to read. If this were an interview, your interviewer would probably not like that.

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco using setters breaks ROI paradigm.

Comment: @Marcell, really making comments about large constructor, in a class with everything `public` and functions working on class properties, that are not its methods... I think there are bigger problems with this code considering OOP paradigm and coding standards at all. lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tree solution is totally wrong for this problem. It's like catching 10e6 tigers and then let go all of them but one, just because you need a single tiger. Very time and memory consuming -- 99.999% of your nodes are useless and should be ignored in the first place.

**Here's another approach**:

- notice your cannot make a dollar to contain more than two 50 cents
- notice again your cannot make a dollar to contain more than four 25 cent coins
- notice... (you get the idea?)

Then your solution is simple:

```
for( int fifty=0; fifty<3; fifty++) {
    for( int quarters=0; quarters<5; quarters++) {
        for( int dimes=0; dimes<11; dimes++) {
            for( int nickels=0; nickels<21; nickels++) {
                int sum = fifty * 50 + quarters * 25 + dimes * 10 + nickels * 5;
                if( sum <= 100 ) counter++;  // here's a combination!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may ask, why did not I do anything about single cent coins? The answer is simple, as soon as the `sum` is less than 100, the rest is filled with 1 cents.

ps. hope this solution is not too simple =)

Comment: I would not go to the extent of calling OP's approch wrong. It should yield a correct answer implemented correctly. Might not be the best. Yours, however, is plain and straight forward and sparing creating nodes for filling everything with 1 cents is clever, if OP would implement it, i think the time complexities would be the same for both approaches. His idea is not that bad. Anyway +1 for simple straight forward approach.

Comment: @luk32 thanks! will the development time be the same for both approaches? i have just typed the code into the python interpreter and got the answer `292` in 0.02sec, the file is 240 bytes long and it took me maybe 5 minutes to type -- about the time OP would need to write the constructor alone, not to mention the rest of the code + debugging time. just my 5 cents =)

Comment: Oh Mate. I never said dev time, or flat execution time. My point was that if you change a dollar to N cents. His solution will be worse only by a constant factor. Of course after /fill rest with cents/ improvement. The number of nodes created should be the same as the number of your `if` gets executed. In terms of algorithms analysis it's just about the same good. Of course yours will be faster, always. And is better overall. However, in my opinion your remarks about OP's approach were excessive. (Though I admit, creating nodes for 1cent paths filling is terrible =)

Comment: You could make this somewhat faster by changing the for condition from quarters < 5 to: (quarters*25) <= (100 - fifty*50)

Comment: for dimes you'd add dimes*10 <= (100 - quarters*25 - fifty*50). for nickels you'd add nickels*5 <= (100 - dimes*10 - quarters*25 - fifty*50)

Comment: And I believe you could just remove the if clause and he sum... and simply do counter++

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco thanks! however, the `if` clause is very important to make the program error-prone. there's actually no point in precise calculation of loop stopping conditions, it's faster to write this way and if coin values change tomorrow, or someone bluntly puts 100 everywhere, the program will still work (though might take 0.01sec longer =)

Comment: I doubt coins will change values any time within this or the next century, nor a dollar change its value from 100 cents.

Comment: @luk32 thanks again! cents' improvement is not that important, it just saved me typing 1 line (and 0.2sec running time in python interpreter, but generally i just really hate typing =)

Comment: @Marcel, and this way we can calculate the right answer right of the bat using dynamic programming approach on paper xD. It's like, ok how many ways are there to build cents of just 1cents. Then, how many ways there is to fit 5 cents fits into 100cents times, how many ways there is to build 5 cents from 1 cents (like if we changed every 5c into 5*1c). Then 10*10c, times number of ways to construct 10c from 5s (and 5s from lower nominals).etc. For a given N=100 we can do it quite fast on paper i believe.

Comment: @lenik, You are mostly welcomed, extrapolation of your idea, and remarks from Marcel led me to another solution! Which probably is something close to what dasblinkenlight suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is not a full answer but might help you.
You can try perform (what i call) a sanity check.
Put a `static` counter in `TrieNode` for every node created, and see how large it grows. If you did some calculations you should be able to tell if it goes to some insane values.

The system can limit the memory available, however it would be really bizarre. Usually the user/admin can set such limits for some purposes. This happens often in dedicated multi-user systems. Other thing could be having a 32bit app in 64bit windows environment. Then mem limit would be 4GB, however this would also be really strange. Any I don't think being limited by the OS is an issue here.

On a side note. I hope you do realize that you kinda defeated all object oriented programming concept with this code :).

Comment: Good suggestions +1. Would add that there are compiler specific switches to set stack size for e.g. gcc has one. But like mentioned above that is probably NOT the problem here

Answer (score 1):

I need more time to analyze your code, but for now I can tell that this is a classic Dynamic Programming problem. You may find some interesting texts here:

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change

and here

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/jaa/CSG713.04F/Information/Handouts/dyn_prog.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to find a solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int w[101];
    memset(w, 0, sizeof(w));
    w[0] = 1;
    int d[] = {1, 5, 10, 25, 50};
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
        for (int k = d[i] ; k <= 100 ; k++) {
            w[k] += w[k-d[i]];
        }
    }
    cout << w[100] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/t1khZN))

The idea is to incrementally build the number of ways to make change by adding coins in progressively larger denomination. Each iteration of the outer loop goes through the results that we already have, and for each amount that can be constructed using the newly added coin adds the number of ways the combination that is smaller by the value of the current coin can be constructed. For example, if the current coin is `5` and the current amount is `7`, the algorithm looks up the number of ways that `2` can be constructed, and adds it to the number of ways that `7` can be constructed. If the current coin is `25` and the current amount is `73`, the algorithm looks up the number of ways to construct `48` (`73-25`) to the previously found number of ways to construct `73`. In the end, the number in `w[100]` represents the number of ways to make one dollar (292 ways).

Comment: That is the most common and decent dynamic programming implementation. It also shows why the hastle with trie was unnecessary. +1 on the solution. But the original code can be corrected too, if the recursion is properly terminated while sum on each node is properly incremented

Answer (score 1):

I really do believe someone has to put the most efficient and simple possible implementation, it is an improvement on lenik's answer:
Memory: Constant
Running time: Considering 100 as **n**, then running time is about O(n (lg(n))) <-*I am unsure*

```
for(int fifty=0; fifty <= 100; fifty+=50)
    for(int quarters=0; quarters <= (100 - fifty); quarters+=25)
        for(int dimes=0; dimes <= (100 - fifty - quarters); dimes+=10)
            counter += 1 + (100 - fifty - quarters - dimes)/5;
```

I think this can be solved in constant time, because any sequence sum can be represented with a linear formula.

Comment: I'm having a series of technical interviews soon, I really do hope I get asked this question. Its classic, and it's easy to remember such a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be infinite recursion. You are not incrementing c any where and loop runs with c<=100

**Edit 1:** I am not sure if

```
int c = Root->Sum+coins[i];
```

is actually taking it beyond 100. Please verify that

**Edit 2:** I missed the Sum being initialized correctly and it was corrected in the comments below.

**Edit 3:** *Method to debug* - 
One more thing that you can do to help is, Write a print function for this tree or rather print on each level as it progresses deeper in the existing code. Add a  counter which terminates loop after say total 10 iterations. The prints would tell you if you are getting garbage values or your c is gradually increasing in a right direction.

Comment: Your suggestions are wrong, sir. Everything seems to be initialized. Sum is initlaized in the constructor. In the main it is set to 0 for the root node, and then when he makes new nodes in here `child = new TrieNode(Root,c);`

Comment: Err yeah - i missed that. That's another reason of such a huge constructor. Will fix the sum part, though i still suspect the recursion being terminated correctly. However, that is not the only suggestion i made :) Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I saw only only "the Sum is uninitialized" and "c will get > 100" which is technically true, but not a problem since ` if(c<=100) {...}`. As long as the total sum of a path would get over 100 such node is not being crated. Cheers.